# Neural network produing same output regardless of input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm currently trying to implement a neural network in Python to play the game of Snake that is trained using a genetic algorithm (although that's a separate matter right now).

Every network that plays the game does the same movement over and over (e.g. continues in a straight line, keeps turning left). There are 5 inputs to the network: the distance to an object (food, a boundary, its own tail) in all four directions, and the angle between the food and the direction the snake is facing. The three outputs represent turning left, continuing straight, and turning right.

I've never worked with anything like this before so I have a fairly basic understanding at this point. The number of hidden layers and the number of nodes per layer is variable, and is something I have been altering a lot to test, but the snakes continue to each repeat the exact same motion.

Any advice on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated, and how to fix it. I can show my code if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may have weights initialized to zero and if they aren't trained properly and stay zero for some reason, neural network will be producing bias as an output always.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I checked the initial values of the weights, they're not 0. The actual value of the outputs is varying, but it always produces the same outcome (for example, output 1 is always the largest output even if its value varies).